# Answers module interfering with Discussion Module

Tags: dotnetnuke, dotnetnuke-8

I am using dnn-8. I have one page which has Answers module. On another page I have added Discussion module. Now I require to add all the post from the answers module in the rightPane of the second page. I did that using existing module and it is showing as i require. But when I click on any topic url of discussion module to view its detail it gives 404 error. It is working perfectly if i remove the Answers module from right pane.
How to resolve that?

If you need any more info, please ask.

[error snapshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/C0jfj.png)

Answer (score 0):

I believe that you are encountering a situation where two modules use a similar URL structure and the information is crossing.  I believe that these modules need to remain on their own separate pages.  Gien this, it isn't exactly possible to change.

Comment: Is there any way I can change the structure. What I require is to show top Questions in side bar on the post page. The answer module is using mobile view to render on the rightPane, can that be causing any problem??

Comment: Not all that easily as it is related to the way the modules handle URLs internally. It would require development effort for sure.